# $G$-equivariant modules and Lie algebra cohomology

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-algebras, lie-algebra-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator\Id{Id}\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}$Is there a link between $G$-equivariant modules and Lie algebra cohomology?

Tell me if I'm mistaken:

1. On one side, if $p:E\longrightarrow M$ is a $G$-bundle (over a complex manifold $M$) where $G$ acts by right translations $(r_g)_{g\in G}$ and $\rho_\mathbb{V} : G \longrightarrow GL(\mathbb{V})$ is a representation of $G$ of finite dimension, we can consider $\mathcal{V}\mathrel{:=}\mathcal{O}_G \otimes \mathbb{V}$ equipped with a linearization $(\phi_g)_{g\in G}$ where: $$\begin{array}{ccccc}\phi_g &:& \mathcal{V} &\longrightarrow & r_g^* \mathcal{V}\\&& (s,U) & \longrightarrow & (\rho_{\mathbb{V}}(g)\circ s \circ r_{g^{-1}},r_g(U)). \end{array}$$
   Such a $G$-equivariant module $\mathcal{V}$ induces a $G$ action on $p_*\mathcal{V}(U)$ defined by $(g \cdot s)(e) = \rho_{\mathbb{V}}(g)(s(e\cdot g^{-1}))$ for all $s\in \mathcal{V}(p^{-1}(U))$. Then $\mathcal{V} = \mathcal{O}_E \otimes p^*(p_* \mathcal{V})^G$ and $(p_*\mathcal{V})^G(M)$ is the set of sections $s \in \mathcal{V}(E)$ invariant by the previous action?
2. The map: $$\begin{array}{ccccc}\varphi_\mathbb{V} &:& \mathbb{V}& \hookrightarrow & \mathcal{V}(E) \\ && v &\longrightarrow & 1_E \otimes v \end{array}$$ is a morphism of the representation $\mathbb{V}$ to the representation $\mathcal{V}(E)$?
3. Now i'm trying to explain the differential $\partial : C^m(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V}) \longrightarrow C^{m+1}(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})$ (where $C^m(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})=\bigwedge^m\mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathbb{V}$ is a $G$-module by the representation $\bigwedge^m\Ad^* \otimes \rho_\mathbb{V}$, if I'm not wrong), by obtaining it as $\varphi_{C^{m+1}(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})}^{-1}\circ d \circ \varphi_{C^m(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})}$.

My problem is that in the article [Cohomology theory of Lie algebras](https://doi.org/10.2307/1990637) of Chevalley–Eilenberg, the link is explained by considering the map $C^m(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})$ which maps $A_1^* \wedge \dotsb \wedge A_m^* \otimes v$ to the equivariant $\mathbb{V}$-valued $m$-form $\omega$ verifying $\omega(\Id_G)=A_1^* \wedge \dotsb \wedge A_m^* \otimes v$. But such a form corresponds to an element of $H^0(G,\Omega^m_G\otimes \mathbb{V})^G$ where the action of $G$ is given by 1. (for the trivial $G$-bundle $p: G \longrightarrow \{\Id_G\}$)? But the action on $C^m(\mathfrak{g},\mathbb{V})$ would be trivial?

Is there a formal way to explain the construction of $\partial$ in terms of 1.?

Comment: The representation $\mathbb V$ defines a $G\times G$-invariant vector bundle structure on the trivial vector bundle $V = G\times \mathbb V$, where the action of right multiplication is given by the representation and the action of left multiplication is trivial, so that the extension of the de Rham differential to $V$-valued differential forms preserves the subspace of left-invariant elements. These are identified with the Chevalley complex by evaluation at the identity element, and right multiplication acts on them as indicated.

Comment: Thanks you so much. However, i still don't understand why in the article of Chevalley and Eilenberg, an equivariant $\mathbb{V}$-valued form is defined as $\omega$ such that : $$\omega \circ Tl_g = \rho_\mathbb{V}(g) \circ \omega$$ where $l_g$ is the left multiplication.

Comment: The above is what I worked out a while ago to get the signs in the Chevalley-Eilenberg complex right. It seems that they are using a slightly different setup, where the $G\times G$-equivariant structure on $G\times\mathbb V$ is trivial for right multiplication and given by the representation for left multiplication. The two equivariant structures are isomorphic by $(g,v)\mapsto (g,\rho(g)v)$, so the two conventions should match up. The main point, that there is a remaining $G$-action on the left $G$-invariants coming from right multiplication, is the same in any case.

Comment: You enlightened me ! Thanks you very much!  I think we share the same convention beacause for me the representation $G\underset{P}{\times} \mathfrak{g}$ has to admit the infinitesimal symetries of the Klein geometry $(G,\omega_G)$, so right invariant vector fields on $G$.